# How to make image on left content on right and responsive when at smaller screen size?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I am trying to create something like image on left and content on right  and alternate order. As you can see my picture below the second one of the image is not on the right side. And is not responsive on smaller screen size. Please help!

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Optional theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

        <title>Example</title>

    <style>
    body {
      margin-top: 50px;
    }

    .img-1 {
      height: 250px;
      width: 350px;
      margin: 10px 50px;

    }


    </style>

      </head>
      <body>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" >
                  <img class="img-1" src="img-1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                     <h3>h3 title</h3>
                    <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                        Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
                        augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
                        tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
                        massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
                        eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" >
                  <img class="img-1" src="img-1.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                     <h3 class="">h3 title</h3>
                    <p class="">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                        Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
                        augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
                        tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
                        massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
                        eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      </body>
    </html>
```

And this is not responsive on smaller screen size, How can I fix it?

[image]

Your help much appriciate!

Comment: switch col-md-6 and col-md-4 on the second.

Comment: @HermLuna Opps... I didn't notice that thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To switch the order so the picture is on the right, in your second row the first div with the class="col-md-6 col-sm-6" should have the h3 and p in it, and then the second div in that row with class="col-md-4 col-sm-4" should have the img in it. To make the images responsive, add the "img-responsive" class in the img tags, and make the height and width you defined in the CSS a max-height or max-width so the images can scale down to a smaller height/width to fit in smaller screens.

Comment: @Chrisy R Opps... I didn't notice that thanks! But what  i mean in responsive is when at smaller screen size, the image and the content is not alternate order. So how can i fix it?

Comment: Oh, I think I understand... you want to switch the order of the image and text when the screen is smaller? Then leave the code you have now but add the col-md-push-x and col-md-pull-x classes. There's an example on the Bootstrap website on the CSS page under Grid System: Column Ordering

Comment: @Chrisy R Hmm... i think your answer were right.  I've tried it out, but I'm still can't add the pull and push on the right way and the result still the same. Do you mind telling me where is the right place to add  col-md-push-x and col-md-pull-x?

Comment: In the second row, the first div with the img in it, the class should be class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-md-push-4 col-sm-push-4" and the second div with the h3 and p should have the class with the pull, class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-pull-6 col-sm-pull-6".   Basically if you think about how it would appear without the push and pull, the first one needs to be pushed however many columns the second takes up, and the second one gets pulled the number of columns the first takes up.

Comment: Thank you for the help and your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `.col-sm-push-*` and `.col-sm-pull-* to switch the ordering of grid columns. Here is reference:`http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering.

To make the images responsive, add the "img-responsive" class in the img tags.

```css
.img-1{ 
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6" >
      <img class="img-1 img-responsive" src="https://pioneerwoman.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/springy-flower-pot-desserts1.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <h3>h3 title</h3>
      <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
    augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
    tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
    massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
    eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
   </div>
 </div>

 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-push-4" >
     <img class="img-1 img-responsive" src="http://www.blog.designsquish.com/images/uploads/jason-whatever-flower-pots.jpg">
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-pull-6">
     <h3 class="">h3 title</h3>
     <p class="">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
    augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
    tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
    massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
    eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

Please click the link to see how it works. https://jsfiddle.net/2d7vab0t/

HTML:

```
<img class="img-1" src="img-1.jpg" width="350px" height="250px">
     <div id="container">
     <h3>h3 title</h3>
                <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
                    augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
                    tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
                    massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
                    eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
                    </div>

<div id="container2">
<img class="img-1" src="img-1.jpg"  width="350px" height="250px">

   <h3 class="">h3 title</h3>
       <p class="">Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.
                    Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra
                    augue. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce dapibus,
                    tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum
                    massa justo sit amet risus. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel
                    eu leo. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.img-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin: 10px 50px;

}

@media only screen and (min-width:768px) {
img {float: left;}
#container2 {clear: left;}
}
```